# List Item <li> containing image <img> not vertically aligning with other <li>'s containing text

Tags: html, css, html-lists

My `<ul>` element has some `<li>`'s containing text, and one containing an image. I want them to appear in a single line, centered horizontally within the parent element, and also their `<li>` contents centered vertically and horizontally. I have the following code:

http://codepen.io/littlemissintrovert/pen/NqqLRr

By far, it's going great, however, I have an issue with the `<li>` containing an `<img>`. It's positioned higher than other `<li>` elements.

I can't find much resources to help me with this issue. Maybe I suck with searching but I found this link: [List items appearing below other list items containing images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107252/list-items-appearing-below-other-list-items-containing-images). It seems we have the same problem and someone suggested there to use:

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

However, when I try to use it, I am unable to center the `<ul>` horizontally, relative to the size of its parent container. Plus, I can't space out my `<li>` elements using margin.

As much as possible, I really want to avoid defining the width. I want my elements to span across the screen 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for fixing `img` issue

- Add `display:block` to the `a` tag as it is a `inline` element
- Add `vertical-align:middle` for the `img` tag as `img` is a `inline` element it will align it vertically middle
- you can also use this technique to add the `margin` on the `left` side of the `li`

> ```
> #mainnav li + li{
>    margin: 0 0 0 3em;
> }
> ```

which will only give style to the next element

demo - http://codepen.io/victorfdes/pen/pJJORw

Comment: Thank you. If you don't mind, I'd also like to ask about keeping my <ul> in a single line. I've tried overflow: hidden. Doesn't seem to fix the job.

Comment: you can use @media query to change the `font` or the `width` for different screen sizes

Answer (score 0):

Just add `vertical-align:middle`  to image will solve your issue:

Check your updated [Codepen Here.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JddaEm)